# Diagonalisation of Matrix with repeated Eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 1\\0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

where we have to solve $x'=Ax$ as a differential equation.

I have found that you get eigenvalues of $1$ and $2$, where $1$ is repeated. I thus need to find the matrix $S$ such that matrix $U= S^{-1}AS$ and solves $Uy=y'$ for some vector $y$ where $x'=Sy'$.

Any help? Thanks :)

Comment: What is $y'$?${}$

Comment: Are there conditions on $U$, $y$, or $y'$ that you're not telling us?  As written I could tell you to take the identity matrix as $S$, $y = e_1$, and $y' = 2e_1$ and all the conditions you have listed would be satisfied.

Comment: You may simply take $S=I$ and $U=A$. As $A$ is invertible, $Ay=y'$ is always solvable for any given $y'$.

Comment: Surely this is a contorted way of asking about the differential equation $y' = Ay$.

Comment: I've edited it to make the question a bit clearer :)

Comment: @SeanyAdams: did you really mean $S^{-1}AS$ or $SAS^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
assume  $n_{\lambda}=dimN(A-\lambda I)$  $m_{\lambda}$ repeated order of  ${\lambda}$ : if $n_{\lambda}=m_{\lambda}$$(\lambda$ generate one eigen vector ) then  calculate eigen vector  $V$ $$(A-\lambda I)v=0$$and if $n_{\lambda}\neq m_{\lambda}$ ($\lambda$ generate K eigen vector )then let $k= m_{\lambda}-n_{\lambda}+1$  then compute $V_i$: i=k,k-1,...,2,1 such that $$(A-\lambda I)^kv_k=0$$$$(A-\lambda I)^{k-1}v_{k}\neq0$$ when find one $V_k$ that satisfy in above condition then $$v_{k-1}=(A-\lambda I)^kv_k$$$$v_{k-2}=(A-\lambda I)^kv_{k-2}$$$$.$$$$.$$ finally $S=[v,v_k,v_{k-1},...,v_{1}]
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 1\\0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$
$$m_1=2,n_1=1$$$$m_2=1,n_2=1$$

Answer (score 0):

The matrix is not diagonalizable as the eigenspace of the eigenvalue 1 has only dimension 1 not 2, you could still make a jordan normal form.